# How to disable App with different versions on Worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have iOS version 2.1 released in app store and I am planning to release 2.1.1, Do we have to deploy the WLAPP file of 2.1.1 to worklight console as well, I have tried it locally on my developement server and What i understand is, it is mandatory to have WLAPP of 2.1.1 so that we can use the disable feature provided by worklight.

Please confirm or add your understanding on same.

Thanks
djrecker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your versions co-existing on the Worklight Server.

If for whatever reason (security bug, fix in native component of the application), you decide that you need to disable the current version and release a fixed version, ... then for this new version you will need to:

1. Upload the new version to the app store, replacing the existing one
2. In Worklight Console, deploy the new .wlapp (that will have a new version number)
3. In Worklight Console, remote disable the previous version with a proper message to be displayed to the users, usually with a link to the app in the store so that they could download it right away.